# How do I avoid the OnDocumentComplete event for embedded iframe elements?

Tags: delphi, iframe, delphi-7, twebbrowser

I want to prevent `iframe` elements from triggering the `OnDocumentComplete` event every time. For example, a page has 4 iframes, and when I load this page, my `OnDocumentComplete` event runs 4 times. I want to run `OnDocumentComplete` just once for every page. How can I do that?

Maybe I could remove or block `iframes` in `TWebBrowser` control.

Comment: I hope you mean hide, not remove. So [`here`](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/56) you have how to find an element and on the found element try to set `Element.Style := 'visibility:hidden;'`.

Comment: Actually I want to prevent them from run OnDocumentComplete event everytime. For example; page has 4 iframe and when i load this page OnDocumentComplete event runs 4 times. I want to run OnDocumentComplete just once for every page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The event [`OnDocumentComplete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete) is fired for each `FRAME`/`IFRAME` in the main document.
If you want to ignore them try this:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
  // check that the event is raised for the top-level browser (not frames or iframes)
  if pDisp = TWebBrowser(Sender).ControlInterface then
  begin
    // do something nice...
  end;
end;
```

---

From Delphi Docs:

> Write an OnDocumentComplete event handler to take specific action when a frame or document is fully loaded into the Web browser. For a document without frames, this event occurs once when the document finishes loading. On a document containing multiple frames, this event occurs once for each frame. When the multiple-frame document finishes loading, the Web browser fires the event one final time.
>
> Sender is the Web browser that is loading the document.
>
> pDisp is the Automation interface of the top-level frame or browser.
>   When loading a document without frames, pDisp is the interface of the
>   Web browser. When loading a document with multiple frames, this is the
>   interface of the containing frame, except for the very last time the
>   event occurs, when it is the interface of the Web browser.

Comment: Would be a nice utility function `InterfaceCompare(x:IDispatch;aObject:TObject)` that wraps that big IF statement.

Comment: @WarrenP, Actually, `if pDisp = TWebBrowser(Sender).ControlInterface then...` will do just fine. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Oh that's great. Maybe a utility function might catch some extraordinary situation (something not assigned or other corner cases?)