# Delphi: WebBrowser's OnDownloadComplete happens multiple times at once

Tags: delphi, events, browser

For example in this code:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DownloadComplete(Sender: TObject);
begin
        ShowMessage('Download Completed');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
        WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.com/');
end;
```

"WebBrowser1DownloadComplete" message appears several times on 1 Navigate.
This is annoying and makes this event almost useless.
Why is this happening? How to avoid this?
Thankyou

Comment: It happens because of frames. Each time this event fires, one frame has been downloaded. Anyway, are you sure you need to watch the `OnDownloadComplete` ? Don't you want to use the `OnDocumentComplete` instead ? For `OnDocumentComplete` you could use [`this advise`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10105697/960757) but for your case can't tell you more.

Comment: So thats why this is happening. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the OnNavigationComplete2 event handler is more suitable for you application.

> Occurs immediately after the Web browser successfully navigates to a
>   new location.
>
> Write an OnNavigateComplete2 event handler to take specific action when the Web browser successfully navigates to a new resource. The event can occur before the document is fully downloaded, but when it occurs at least part of the document must be received and a viewer for the document created.

Comment: OnNavigateComplete2 too behaved like this but meh, I decided to go with it instead of against it. Thanks for the info about it.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It neither explains nor solves the problem, which are the two things the question requested.

Comment: Because there is no other answer and the system was constantly annoying me to pick the best answer thus I had to do that.